# Filter by month name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I want to retrieve data on the basis of months. I want to get worksheet data between two months following is my query but it doesn't work fine.

```
SELECT  (CONVERT(varchar(3), DATENAME(month, w.ExpectedStartDate)) +  '-' +     CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), datepart(yyyy, w.ExpectedStartDate))) as MonthName

    FROM Worksheet w LEFT OUTER JOIN StatusType st ON st.StatusTypeId = w.StatusTypeId
    WHERE w.ProjectId = 20
    AND CONVERT(varchar(3), DATENAME(month, w.ExpectedStartDate)) between ('Jan')     AND ('Apr')
```

When i convert it to this:

```
SELECT  (CONVERT(varchar(3), DATENAME(month, w.ExpectedStartDate)) +  '-' +     CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), datepart(yyyy, w.ExpectedStartDate))) as MonthName

        FROM Worksheet w LEFT OUTER JOIN StatusType st ON st.StatusTypeId = w.StatusTypeId
        WHERE w.ProjectId = 20
        AND CONVERT(varchar(3), DATENAME(month, w.ExpectedStartDate)) between ('Jan')     AND ('Mar')
```

I have just changed `ToMonth = Mar` rather than Apr. then it shows me record which is correct because there is data for march. for April why it doesn't show any thing?

Please give your suggestion.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine it doesn't like the fact you've used BETWEEN with strings; the string 'Apr' comes before the string 'Jan' so it doesn't work, but the string 'Mar' comes after the string 'Jan'.

Comment: I'd use DATEPART rather than DATENAME to get an integer that represents your month, Jan = 1, Feb = 2, etc. So your where clause would become `WHERE w.ProjectId = 20 AND DATEPART(month, w.ExpectedStartDate) BETWEEN 1 AND 4` (for Jan to April).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Month(w.ExpectedStartDate) between 1 AND 4

Answer (score 0):

```
AND MONTH(w.ExpectedStartDate)>=1 AND MONTH(w.ExpectedStartDate)<=4
```

Answer (score 0):

For accuracy use this code

```
w.ExpectedStartDate>='20110101' and ExpectedStartDate<'20110105'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this query frequently, you could also investigate persisted computed columns - e.g. something like:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Worksheet 
  ADD YearMonth AS 
        RIGHT('0000' + CAST(YEAR(ExpectedStartDate) AS VARCHAR(4)), 4) + 
        RIGHT('00' + CAST(MONTH(ExpectedStartDate) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) PERSISTED
```

This will add a new column `YearMonth` to your table that is always up to date, always accurate, and it's persisted, e.g. stored on disk so it's fast, you can even put an index on that column!

That column will contains values such as

```
201103
201104
```

and so forth - the year (four digits) and month (two digits, leading zero) of your `ExpectedStartDate`

So to select all projects for January 2011, you can define:

```
 SELECT (list of columns)
 FROM dbo.Worksheet
 WHERE YearMonth = '201101'
```

and get exactly those rows very quickly - especially if you index this column.